# How can I prevent log growth in SQL Server when insert millions of records

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an insert query that needs to insert 50 million records, but when I execute this query, my database log file grows to 100GB and stops because of disk full.

How can I prevent log file from growing?

Comment: Change to simple recovery model

Comment: A good read: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/managing-the-sql-server-transaction-log-dealing-with-explosive-log-growth/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that when useing "WITH (TABLOCK)" the query dont log. I solved it. Hope work for you.
query would be like this : INSERT INTO TargetTable WITH (TABLOCK).

and recover model must be simple.